# Issue with condition in headerright

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I try to add a conditional button in headerright but I get an error message that (probably) says this is not the way to go. I am sure the error is in the condition within the headerright of the stacknavbigator, since when I try with a straight button it works.

This is the stacknavigator code

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Loading: Loading,
    SignUp: SignUp,
    Login: Login,
    Main: Main,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Loading',

    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerLeft: null,
      headerRight: 
      () => (
        if this.loggedIn: true {

          <Button
          onPress={() => alert('I know you')}
          title="Log-out"
          color="#fff"
          />
        }

        else {
          <Button
          onPress={() => alert('Please log in')}
          title="Log-in"
          color="#fff"
          />
             }
      );
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#c6f1e7',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#59616e',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontFamily: 'Raleway-Regular',
        fontWeight: '400',
      },
    },
  },
);
```

Where the fucntion in headerright is causing this error:

```
Error: TransformError SyntaxError: /Users/tim/Dropbox/co-own.it/apps/kowop/App.js: Unexpected token (33:8)

  31 |       headerLeft: null,
  32 |       headerRight: () => (
> 33 |         if this.loggedIn: true {
     |         ^
  34 |           <Button
  35 |           onPress={() => alert('I know you')}
  36 |           title="Log-out"

showCompileError
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:34606:26
<unknown>
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:34545:29
emit
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:35025:35
<unknown>
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:34872:23
dispatchEvent
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:32343:31
<unknown>
```

Can anyone point me in the good direction, since I can't really find the answer?

Thanks a lot!

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In header right you need to change the code:

```
 headerRight: 
      () => {
        let button = this.loggedIn? (

          <Button
          onPress={() => alert('I know you')}
          title="Log-out"
          color="#fff"
          />
        )

        : (
          <Button
          onPress={() => alert('Please log in')}
          title="Log-in"
          color="#fff"
          />
             )

return button;
      };
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Wonderful Gaurav, that did it!

Comment: Glad it helped. Do upvote too if you think it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a '(' where you should use a '{' when defining the function

```
   headerRight: () => (
```

should be

```
headerRight: () => {

    code goes here
}
```